# pandas merging two columns treated as a "set"

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a simple way in pandas to do merge rows where we treat a group of columns as set. For example A, B are a set.

```
  A B C
0 a b 1
1 b a 3
2 c c 1
3 d a 5
```

so I want merging on=[A,B] to give me:

```
  A B C1 C2
0 a b 1  3
2 c c 1  Nan
3 d a 5  Nan
```

Comment: I am trying to create a new row combining A and B strings in alphabetical order and having trouble since the string ordering does not work

Comment: What do you mean string ordering does not work?

Comment: df[['A','B']].min(axis=1) / df['A'] > df['B'] / str(df['A']) > str (df['B']) don't return the Boolean value I expect.

Answer (score 5):

IIUC, you can use

#### `np.sort`+`groupby`

```
d = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['A', 'B']].values,1))
     
df.groupby((d!=d.shift()).cumsum().sum(1)).C.agg(list).apply(pd.Series)

    0   1
2   1.0 3.0
4   1.0 NaN
6   5.0 NaN
```

or

#### `frozenset`+`apply`

```
df.groupby(df[['A', 'B']].apply(frozenset,1)).C.agg(list).apply(pd.Series)


        0   1
(a, b)  1.0 3.0
(c)     1.0 NaN
(a, d)  5.0 NaN
```